# How to drag and drop the image above to the below image where if 1st image on top is touch with the 1st image below will provide value to be recorded

Tags: java, user-interface

```
package project; 
import java.awt.Color; 
import java.awt.Component;``
import java.awt.Point; 
import java.awt.Toolkit; 
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter; 
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.net.MalformedURLException; 
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon; 
import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import javax.swing.JLabel; 
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DragImage {
       private JLayeredPane contentPane;    JLabel[] draggableImage= new JLabel[11];    ImageIcon[] image = new ImageIcon[11];   
ImageIcon Imagebox = new ImageIcon();    JLabel[] box = new
JLabel[11];
      public DragImage() throws MalformedURLException {
       JFrame frame = new JFrame(DragImage.class.getSimpleName());
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       contentPane = new JLayeredPane();
       contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
       contentPane.setOpaque(true);
       frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
       frame.setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
       frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
       frame.setVisible(true);
       image[1] = new ImageIcon("1.png");
       image[2] = new ImageIcon("2.png");
       image[3] = new ImageIcon("3.png");
       image[4] = new ImageIcon("4.png");
       image[5] = new ImageIcon("5.png");
       image[6] = new ImageIcon("6.png");
       image[7] = new ImageIcon("7.png");
       image[8] = new ImageIcon("8.png");
       image[9] = new ImageIcon("9.png");
       image[10] = new ImageIcon("10.png");


       Imagebox = new ImageIcon("box1.png");
       MouseDragger dragger = new MouseDragger();
       Random random = new Random();
       int total = 10;
       int x=135;
       for(int i=1;i<11;i++)
       {
        draggableImage[i] = new JLabel(image[i]);
           draggableImage[i].setSize(120,120);
           draggableImage[i].setLocation(total,20);
           dragger.makeDraggable(draggableImage[i]);
           contentPane.add(draggableImage[i]);

           box[i] = new JLabel(Imagebox);
           box[i].setSize(120,120);`enter code here`enter code here`
           box[i].setLocation(total,contentPane.getHeight()-150);
           dragger.makeDraggable(box[i]);
           contentPane.add(box[i]);

           total += x;
       }
       contentPane.repaint();       }
       public static class MouseDragger extends MouseAdapter {
       private Point lastLocation;
       private Component draggedComponent;
       private int ans;

       @Override
       public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
           draggedComponent = e.getComponent();
           lastLocation = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(draggedComponent, e.getPoint(),   
draggedComponent.getParent());
       }

       @Override
       public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
           Point location = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(draggedComponent, e.getPoint(),   
draggedComponent.getParent());
           if (draggedComponent.getParent().getBounds().contains(location)) {
               Point newLocation = draggedComponent.getLocation();
               newLocation.translate(location.x - lastLocation.x, location.y - lastLocation.y);
               newLocation.x = Math.max(newLocation.x, 0);
               newLocation.x = Math.min(newLocation.x, draggedComponent.getParent().getWidth() -   
draggedComponent.getWidth());
               newLocation.y = Math.max(newLocation.y, 0);
               newLocation.y = Math.min(newLocation.y, draggedComponent.getParent().getHeight() -   
draggedComponent.getHeight());
               draggedComponent.setLocation(newLocation);
               lastLocation = location;

           }
       }


       @Override
       public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
           lastLocation = null;
           draggedComponent = null;

       }

       public void makeDraggable(Component component) {
           component.addMouseListener(this);
           component.addMouseMotionListener(this);
       }
       }
       public static void main(String[] args) {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

           @Override
           public void run() {
               try {
                   new DragImage();
               } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       });    } }
```

Comment: How to test your code when you don't provide the images or runnable code?

Comment: im new here. every time i edit it, it still show errors.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use Jlabels and add them MouseEvents so when you drag mouse above of them, they can drop below. 
Second, for below images you should calculate their positons and their widths so you can find whether above images drop over below images. I created a picture for you to understand. You should make the all above images fulfill these two conditions. Here[image]

And I'm going to add codes here. Actually I tried a few times, I think it's working as you want.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;


public class Example {

    private JFrame frame;
    JLabel iconBelow1;
    JLabel iconBelow2;
    JLabel iconBelow3;
    int x1;
    int x2;
    int x3;
    int w1;
    int w2;
    int w3;
    int point;
    JLabel pointArea;
    JLabel icon1;
    JLabel icon2;
    JLabel icon3;
    JLabel icon4;
    JLabel icon5;
    int c = 0;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Example window = new Example();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Example() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 381);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        icon1 = new JLabel("");
        icon1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Gizem\\Desktop\\yellowTree.jpg"));
        icon1.setBounds(24, 55, 46, 48);
        panel.add(icon1);

        icon2 = new JLabel("");
        icon2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Gizem\\Desktop\\flower.jpg"));
        icon2.setBounds(115, 55, 59, 48);
        panel.add(icon2);

        icon3 = new JLabel("");
        icon3.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Gizem\\Desktop\\2.jpg"));
        icon3.setBounds(207, 55, 46, 48);
        panel.add(icon3);

        icon4 = new JLabel("New label");
        icon4.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Gizem\\Desktop\\4.jpg"));
        icon4.setBounds(286, 55, 46, 48);
        panel.add(icon4);

        icon5 = new JLabel("New label");
        icon5.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Gizem\\Desktop\\6.jpg"));
        icon5.setBounds(378, 55, 46, 48);
        panel.add(icon5);

        iconBelow1 = new JLabel("");
        iconBelow1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Gizem\\Desktop\\back.jpg"));
        iconBelow1.setBounds(0, 226, 109, 25);
        panel.add(iconBelow1);

        iconBelow2 = new JLabel("New label");
        iconBelow2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Gizem\\Desktop\\back.jpg"));
        iconBelow2.setBounds(356, 226, 68, 25);
        panel.add(iconBelow2);

        iconBelow3 = new JLabel("New label");
        iconBelow3.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Gizem\\Desktop\\back.jpg"));
        iconBelow3.setBounds(205, 226, 75, 25);
        panel.add(iconBelow3);

        pointArea = new JLabel("Point:");
        pointArea.setBounds(10, 11, 46, 14);
        panel.add(pointArea);

        MyListener listener = new MyListener();
        icon1.addMouseListener(listener);
        icon2.addMouseListener(listener);
        icon3.addMouseListener(listener);
        icon4.addMouseListener(listener);
        icon5.addMouseListener(listener);

        System.out.println(iconBelow1.getX());
        System.out.println(iconBelow2.getX());
        System.out.println(iconBelow3.getX());

        x1 = iconBelow1.getX();
        x2 = iconBelow2.getX();
        x3 = iconBelow3.getX();
        w1 = iconBelow1.getWidth();
        w2 = iconBelow2.getWidth();
        w3 = iconBelow3.getWidth();


    }
private  class MyListener implements MouseListener {



        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {


        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            int a = ((JLabel) e.getSource()).getX();
            int b = ((JLabel) e.getSource()).getY();
            System.out.println("Position X : " + a + " " + "Position Y : " + b);
            b += 210;
            //b += 150;

            ((JLabel) e.getSource()).setLocation(a, b);
            if(((JLabel) e.getSource()) == icon1 ){

                if (a  < iconBelow1.getX() + iconBelow1.getWidth() && !(iconBelow1.getX() > a + ((JLabel) e.getSource()).getWidth()) ){
                    point += 1;
                    pointArea.setText(Integer.toString(point));

                }
                else if (a  < iconBelow2.getX() + iconBelow2.getWidth() && !(iconBelow2.getX()  > a + ((JLabel) e.getSource()).getWidth()) ){
                    point += 1;
                    pointArea.setText(Integer.toString(point));

                }
                else if (a  < iconBelow3.getX() + iconBelow3.getWidth() && !(iconBelow3.getX()  > a + ((JLabel) e.getSource()).getWidth() )){
                    point += 1;
                    pointArea.setText(Integer.toString(point));

                }
            }
            else if(((JLabel) e.getSource()) == icon2 ){

                if (a  < iconBelow1.getX() + iconBelow1.getWidth() && !(iconBelow1.getX() > a + ((JLabel) e.getSource()).getWidth() )){
                    point += 1;
                    pointArea.setText(Integer.toString(point));
                }
                else if (a  < iconBelow2.getX() + iconBelow2.getWidth() && !(iconBelow2.getX()  > a + ((JLabel) e.getSource()).getWidth() )){
                    point += 1;
                    pointArea.setText(Integer.toString(point));
                }
                else if (a  < iconBelow3.getX() + iconBelow3.getWidth() && !(iconBelow3.getX()  > a + ((JLabel) e.getSource()).getWidth() )){
                    point += 1;
                    pointArea.setText(Integer.toString(point));
                }
            }
            else if(((JLabel) e.getSource()) == icon3 ){

                if (a  < iconBelow1.getX() + iconBelow1.getWidth() && !(iconBelow1.getX() > a + ((JLabel) e.getSource()).getWidth() )){
                    point += 1;
                    pointArea.setText(Integer.toString(point));
                }
                else if (a  < iconBelow2.getX() + iconBelow2.getWidth() && !(iconBelow2.getX()  > a + ((JLabel) e.getSource()).getWidth() )){
                    point += 1;
                    pointArea.setText(Integer.toString(point));
                }
                else if (a  < iconBelow3.getX() + iconBelow3.getWidth() && !(iconBelow3.getX()  > a + ((JLabel) e.getSource()).getWidth() )){
                    point += 1;
                    pointArea.setText(Integer.toString(point));
                }
            }
            else if(((JLabel) e.getSource()) == icon4 ){

                if (a  < iconBelow1.getX() + iconBelow1.getWidth() && !(iconBelow1.getX() > a + ((JLabel) e.getSource()).getWidth() )){
                    point += 1;
                    pointArea.setText(Integer.toString(point));
                }
                else if (a  < iconBelow2.getX() + iconBelow2.getWidth() && !(iconBelow2.getX()  > a + ((JLabel) e.getSource()).getWidth() )){
                    point += 1;
                    pointArea.setText(Integer.toString(point));
                }
                else if (a  < iconBelow3.getX() + iconBelow3.getWidth() && !(iconBelow3.getX()  > a + ((JLabel) e.getSource()).getWidth() )){
                    point += 1;
                    pointArea.setText(Integer.toString(point));
                }
            }
            else if(((JLabel) e.getSource()) == icon5 ){

                if (a  < iconBelow1.getX() + iconBelow1.getWidth() && !(iconBelow1.getX()  > a + ((JLabel) e.getSource()).getWidth() )){
                    point += 1;
                    pointArea.setText(Integer.toString(point));
                }
                else if (a  < iconBelow2.getX() + iconBelow2.getWidth() && !(iconBelow2.getX() > a + ((JLabel) e.getSource()).getWidth() )){
                    point += 1;
                    pointArea.setText(Integer.toString(point));
                }
                else if (a  < iconBelow3.getX() + iconBelow3.getWidth() && !(iconBelow3.getX() > a + ((JLabel) e.getSource()).getWidth() )){
                    point += 1;
                    pointArea.setText(Integer.toString(point));
                }
            }




        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
}
```

Note: I tried to answer your question the way I understood. Did you want to do something like that or you meant a different something?